# How to change my own dataset to MNIST dataset format?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist

```
data_transform_test = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                          transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
                                          transforms.Resize((28, 28)),
                                          transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
                                          ])
```

This is what I tried for my implementation of a model that is based on MNIST dataset. I cannot change the entire model architecture because that is too much of a burden for me. But my code is giving me this error. Do you guys have any suggestions more any modifications needed?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-ce644b7b7998> in <module>()
      1 # training for 3 epochs
      2 n_epochs = 3
----> 3 losses = train(capsule_net, criterion, optimizer, n_epochs=n_epochs)

<ipython-input-58-54eb5db28cd7> in train(capsule_net, criterion, optimizer, n_epochs, print_every)
     26 
     27             # reshape and get target class
---> 28             target = torch.eye(10).index_select(dim=0, index=target)
     29 
     30             if TRAIN_ON_GPU:

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Comment: What's the shape of your data out of your dataloader?

Comment: It's 75 × 50 with color scale

Comment: Actually, since your error is from `target = torch.eye(10).index_select(dim=0, index=target)`, I think the error is in your targets. What is the value of `target` at the error? It cannot be > 9.